# Inside Table Cascading Delete

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
id     name     parent_id
1      node1    0
2      node2    1
3      node3    1
4      node4    2
5      node5    2
6      node6    5
.      .        .
.      .        .
.      .        .
```

it can shows like:

```
node1--->node2--->node4
     |        |
     |        --->node5--->node6
     |
     --->node3
```

I want when a parent is removed, all its children will also be deleted. How can I do?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already?

Comment: Currently I use an additional column that is for the parent hierarchy. like: 0>1>2>5
And I use it to find the children of a parent.
This is not a good idea, especially when I change a child's parent, the hierarchy column of all children of that child must change.

Comment: I meant code, what code have you written to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find a code to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the following [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985915/php-recursive-function-to-delete-all-child-nodes-causes-stackoverflow](link)

Comment: Don't put [solved] in the title, explain how it is solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with database feature, "[DELETE ON CASCADE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)". 
Whenever we define a foreign key, we have option to enable deletion cascading, so that referred row is automatically deleted whenever parent row is deleted.

Such as

```
create table Nodes(id int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
               name varchar(20),
               parent_id int null,
               constraint FK_ID_With_CascadeDelete
               foreign key (parent_id)
               REFERENCES Nodes(id)
               ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Refer following link for a sample, showing deletion of Node2 is deleting all childs.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1d43/1/0

Note: As "Delete on Cascade" feature need a foreign key to be defined, so in parent_id a 'null' need to be used instead of 0, for nodes without parent.