# Delete all child nodes and parent nodes using with PHP recursive function

Tags: php, recursion, sql-delete

I have a problem deleting all child nodes and parent nodes using with PHP recursive function. The database table structure is followed the tree structure.

Below is sample table structure:

`MySQL Table: folders`

```html
id    name    parentid
1      A1         0
2      A1-1       1
3      A1-2       2
4      A1-3       3
5      A2         0
6      A2-1       5
7      A2-2       6
8      A2-3       7
```

```html
id = the id of the category
name= folder name
parent = the id of the parent category
```

According to the table: folders. For example, if I want to delete id is `1`, following the child nodes (id are `2,3,4`) should be deleted.

I am followed the below sample coding to do the delete recursive function, but can't work and crashes.

```
<?php
function remrecurs($id) {
    $qlist= mysqli_query($sql_connection,"SELECT * FROM folders WHERE parentid='$id'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($qlist)>0) {
        while($curitem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qlist)) {
remrecurs($curitem['id']);
} 
} mysqli_query($sql_connection,"DELETE FROM folders WHERE id='$id'"); 
}
  remrecurs(1);
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985915/php-recursive-function-to-delete-all-child-nodes-causes-stackoverflow
I am referring to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of the question you mention is correct, but the implementation on your code is not.

You're using `$sql_connection` but that variable is not available in your function. Assuming `$sql_connection`, to use it in a function you need to make it `global`

Furthermore as @Dharman mentioned in their comment, you should always use prepared statements when using parameters in your query.

Also while debugging, always ensure that you add the proper error reporting information with `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` so that you can quickly identify the issues with your queries.

I've refactored your code to have the recursion work correctly:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
function remrecurs($id) {
    global $sql_connection;
    $query = "SELECT id FROM folders WHERE parentid=?";
    if ($stmt = $sql_connection->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            remrecurs($data['id']);
        }
    }
    $delete = 'DELETE FROM folders WHERE id = ?';
    $stmt = $sql_connection->prepare($delete);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
remrecurs(1);
```